# Inverse Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $(X,\Vert . \Vert)$ be a Banach space, assume that {${T_n}$} is a sequence of invertible operators in B(X) which converges to T $\in$ B(X). Suppose also that ${\Vert T_n ^{-1}\Vert}<1$, $\forall$ n$\in$ $\mathbb{N}$. $\\$ Show that T is invertible.

I don't even have an idea on how to go about this problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that $\|T_n\|^{-1}<1$ for all $n$?

Comment: About the bound, is it really $\|T\|^{-1} < 1$, or is it $\|T_n\|^{-1} < 1$? Because of the $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ part after that.

Comment: That is how the question is given. But is see light in your observation, I think the correct thing should be  $\|T_n\|^{-1} < 1$. Thanks.

Comment: @VincentEbuka Does this question come from a book or lecture notes? I believe there is some error.

Comment: The lecturer wrote it that way on the board, as an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
Try to use the data you are given to conclude that for some $n$, we have 
$$\|TT^{-1}_n-1\|<1.$$
Because then by a standard argument, $TT_n^{-1}$ is invertible, and therefore $T$ is invertible with inverse $T^{-1}=T_n^{-1}(TT_n^{-1})^{-1}$.

Comment: Please where does the (-1) in $\|TT^{-1}_n-1\|<1$ come from. More explanation will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: We have $\|TT_n^{-1}-1\|=\|TT_n^{-1}-T_nT_n^{-1}\|\leq\|T-T_n\|\|T_n^{-1}\|$, so you want to get bounds on $\|T-T_n\|$ and $\|T_n^{-1}\|$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But I was thinking the expression $T^{-1}=T_n^{-1}(TT_n^{-1})^{-1}$ would be equal to Identity, $I$. Which shows that  $TT_n^{-1}$ is invertible. But instead it equals $T^{-1}$. Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: No.  If $T,S\in B(X)$ with $S$ and $TS$ invertible, then $TS(TS)^{-1}=I$, and $S(TS)^{-1}T=S(TS)^{-1}TSS^{-1}=SS^{-1}=1$, so $T$ is invertible with $T^{-1}=S(TS)^{-1}$.

Comment: Waw...Bravo. Thanks alot. I get it now. I am grateful.

Comment: Let ${c_n}$ $\in \ell^{\infty}$, and let $T_{c_n}$$\in$ B$(\ell^2)$, $\:$ be defined by $\\$

 $T_{c_n}$ ({$x_n$}) = {$c_nx_n$}. $\\$

 1. If inf {$\vert c_n \vert$: n $\in\mathbb{N}$} $\gt$ 0 , and $d_n$ = $\cfrac{1}{c_n}$ , $\\$

Show that $d_n$ $\in$ $\ell^{\infty}$, $\;$  and that $\:$ $T_{c_n}$$T_{d_n}$ = $T_{d_n}$$T_{c_n}$= I .$\\$

 2. If ${c_n}$ = $\cfrac{1}{n}$ ,$\:$ Show that $T_{c_n}$ is not invertible. $\\$ 

Please, can I have your take on it.

Comment: What are you having issue with?

Comment: In part (2) of the problem. Is it sufficient to say: If ${c_n} = \cfrac{1}{n}$, then ${d_n} = \cfrac{1}{c_n} = n $. And since $\ell^{\infty}$ is a space of all bounded sequence, $d_n \notin {\cal l}^{\infty}$. Thus $T_{c_n}$ is not invertible. Does it make sense and sufficient to answer the question. Thanks

Comment: You have the intuition, but I would not call that argument rigorous.  Here's one way to make it rigorous:  Assume you have an inverse $S$ of $T_{c_n}$.  Looking at how $S$ acts on the basis vectors of $\ell^2$, determine that $\|S\|>n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, a contradiction.

Comment: How is the $\|S\|$ greater than $n$. I don't seem to understand it. Thanks.

Comment: Because if $e_n$ denotes the $n$th standard basis vector of $\ell^2$, then $e_n=ST_{c_n}e_n=\frac{1}{n}Se_n$, so $Se_n=ne_n$.